# Receiving a validation error detected: Value '[AWS:RDS::DBInstance]' at 'typeNameList' failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I am trying to create an RDS server running MySQL database and receiving the following error:

`1 validation error detected: Value '[AWS:RDS::DBInstance]' at 'typeNameList' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy constraint: [Member must have length less than or equal to 204, Member must have length greater than or equal to 10, Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [A-Za-z0-9]{2,64}::[A-Za-z0-9]{2,64}::[A-Za-z0-9]{2,64}(::MODULE){0,1}]`

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Parameters:
  DBName:
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'
  MUser:
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*'
  MPass:
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: '[a-zA-Z0-9]*'
    Description: "It shouldn't be less than 8 characters"
    
Resources:
  MyDBInstance:
    Type: AWS:RDS::DBInstance
    Properties:
      DBName: !Ref DBName
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref MUser
      MasterUserPassword: !Ref MPass
      Engine: MySQL
      DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
      StorageType: gp2
      PubliclyAccessible: True
      AllocatedStorage: "20"
      DBInstanceIdentifier: !Join ["-", [ "MyDBInstance", !Ref "AWS::Region" ]]
      AvailabilityZone: !Select [1, !GetAZs ""]
```

Comment: Hi. I've noticed that all your questions got answered and not a single one was ever accepted. Accepting good answers is a good practice and and reduces duplicates. @PatMyron is good you even write "It worked. thank you", so why not accept it?

Answer (score 30):

Missing a colon. Should be `AWS::RDS::DBInstance`

Recommend the [CloudFormation Linter](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-python-lint/) in [VSCode](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cfn-lint-visual-studio-code) to see these errors inline while authoring templates along with autocompletion and documentation links:

[image: Visual Studio Code extension example screenshot]

Comment: are there any linters that would show errors as you type them rather than running from command line?

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. Upvoted your answer of course :)
In my case it was AWS::IAM:Role - missing a colon before Role.

Comment: It's amazing how much trouble this small typo creates in CF, and how long it takes to get a (pretty vague) error message.  I'll have to grab the linter for sure!

Comment: This should be marked as a correct Answer.